# Syntax Error In JS function, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a syntax error on line 15, I don't know why.

Also, are there other ways to call functions? I'm adding this event on click, but I think it's incorrect. I think I need to use return or something else, or write a function to call it.

```js
var toDolist = function() {
    
    addNewTask = function () {
        
        var btn2 = document.getElementById("add-task-box");
        btn2.onclick = addNewTask
        
        
        var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value,
            itemTexts = input,
            colA = document.getElementById('task-col-a').children.length,
            colB = document.getElementById('task-col-b').children.length,
            taskBoks = document.createElement("div"),
            
            taskBoks.className = "min-box",
            taskBoks.innerHTML = '<div class="col-3 chack" id=""><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div><div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent">/
            <p>'+itemTexts+'</p></div><div class="col-1 color"></div>'
            
            if (colB > colA) {
                var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-a");
            } else {
                var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-b");
            }
                todolist.appendChild(taskBoks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have commas where there should be semicolons, for instance after declaring `taskBoks`, and certainly after setting a `className` etc.

Comment: First step: indent your code correctly. It makes it much easier to spot errors. Second: you have a comma after declaring `taskBoks`. For the purposes of this code, you can only use the comma to separate new variable declarations. `taskBoks.className = "min-box"` is not declaring a new variable to the previous statement should end with a semicolon.

Comment: Vladimirs: One issue is it seems you tried to escape a line break in your string, but used / instead of \.

Comment: Also you are assigning the function to an onclick inside the function you assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a number of variables in series, using `,` to declare them all in a single `var` statement. But as shown below, you are trying to declare `taskBoks.className`, which is not a variable name, it's referring to an object property (`className`) of an object (`taskBoks`).

```js
// Declare variables, one after another...
var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value,
    itemTexts = input,
    colA = document.getElementById('task-col-a').children.length,
    colB = document.getElementById('task-col-b').children.length,
    taskBoks = document.createElement("div"),

    // Since previous line ends in comma, this is another declaration...
    taskBoks.className = "min-box",
    // Syntax Error: variable names can't contain a dot.
```

You probably just need to change the comma at the end of the `taskBoks` declaration to be a semicolon, to end the `var` statement.

Also, you'll need to change the comma at the end of the `taskBoks.className` line to a semicolon.
And repeat for the following line, `taskBoks.innerHTML`, or you'll just get another exception thrown when it reaches that point.

And you have a multi-line string in the assignment of `taskBoks.innerHTML`, which is probably not going to work in all engines and may be a syntax error...

And you're trying to assign `btn2`'s click handler to a function, from inside that function... that probably belongs in `toDolist` instead(?) or someplace else.

In other words you have numerous other issues here, but the comma is the cause of the specific error the question asks about. You should probably split this situation into a few separate questions about specific errors you run into, instead of spitting the whole blob out in one question and asking "why is my code broken?"

Comment: thank you it was very helpful but i don't understand why my code still not working

Comment: @Vladimirs As you can see, your question has been put on hold as being off-topic. I suggest you look at the help center links that are provided in the hold notice and figure out a more specific question to ask. "My code isn't working" is generally not going to get good answers - posting the code and a specific error will. Note that I explained why you got this syntax error, but the broader question of why your code doesn't work needs to be narrowed down. I suggest posting another question with a specific issue and an error message.

Comment: thank you very much!! Have nice day!!!

Comment: @Vladimirs You're welcome. I have also updated my answer to be a bit more specific about the `var` statement error, in case it was not clear enough before.